# Removing the index reading from excel files with Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

How to remove the unnamed column? I know that with csv files

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df.to_excel('Excel_Sample2.xlsx', sheet_name = 'NewSheet',index = False)
```

Result:

[image]

The 'index = False' is working with dealing with CSV files, what is possible to do on excel?

CSV example:

[image]

The excel file - [image]

Comment: `index=False` works fine to prevent writing the index. I cannot reproduce your issue

Comment: @adirk It would be helpful if you could also include the code that you used to import the excel file

Comment: It's actually just a file of excel. I didn't write it but I just attached another photo which is the looks of the excel file

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your error - from my side, I see "Unnamed: 0" because your cell A1 in your excel sheet is empty...
I believe if you check that first cell in your dataframe before exporting to Excel , you should see the issue

```
df.columns[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `.csv` while saving the file. Try:
`df.to_csv('My_Output.csv', index=False)`